# How to mock a class member object method which got called from an inner class

Tags: java, testing, mockito, junit5

I want to write a test for class A which has an inner class C and private member class B. A calls class C  and  C calls one private method of A to execute 'make' behaviour B. Below code will give you the clarity.

I want to mock B and mock behaviour B.make. Please suggest a solution. I am writing a test for class A

```
public class A {
    private ArkSolver B = new ArkSolver()
    void someMethod(){
       new C().plan();
    }

    private ArkTripPlan private2ofA (Ark ark) throws VRPSolverException {
        ArkTripPlan tripPlan = B.make(arg1,arg2,arg3);

        return tripPlan;
    }

    private class C {
        private Ark leafArk;

        public ArkTripPlan plan() throws VRPSolverException {
            return private2ofA (leafArk);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Show what you have done so far and why it does not work and / or what exceptions are you getting

Comment: Inject your `B` in the `A` constructor. If you have a good reason to make `B` private, make it implement an interface in a wider access.

Comment: There are 0 `public` methods that take parameters, I don't see how you could possibly write tests for this as there are no input/output parameters that you could check.  In general, only public methods should be mocked, and the rest considered as a black box (mocking private details would mean your test breaks if private details changed), avoid that if you can.